MAUI Android storage
Idea is to save files inside Phone/Android/data/<app_package>/... directory and check them via File manager, like other application data is stored in phone e.g. Phone/Android/data/com.whatsapp and so on.
however I cannot target that location.
I've got included permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

also set preffered Install location = preferExternal in manifest.
        protected static readonly string _root = Path.Combine(
#if ANDROID
            Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath,
#endif
            "Library"
        );

...

Directory.CreateDirectory(_root);
File.WriteAllBytes(
    Path.Combine(_root, "test.txt"),
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("red panda")
);

here i expect Phone/Android/data/com.myApp/files/Library/test.txt to be created. However when i open that using File manager files dir is empty.
Tried FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory but still

Do you use the File picker to select files ?

No, I download from network or create local cache files and save them.
The thing is using ADB I'm able  to extract these files, they've been stored in 'private' or something storage. However I want them to be 'public' and accessible for phone File manager

Have you solved the problem ? I did as what Bhavanesh  said, and it worked.

unfortunately, no


Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath

You're storing your file on External app-specific directory. Files here are private, accessible by the app but are not directly visible in file managers due to Scoped Storage Restrictions. Storing files to this path doesn't even require Storage permissions.
If you want your files to be public and accessible for phone File Manager. You need to store you files in External storage public directory. Ex: Downloads
string downloadsPath = global::Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads)?.AbsolutePath;
string filePath = Path.Combine(downloadsPath, "example.txt");

File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello, Downloads!");

This will write the file to your device downloads folder.
OR
if want see your files in your app specific directories through phone file manager you can store you files in ObbDirectory or MediaDirectory of external storage.
 string obbDirPath = Android.App.Application.Context.ObbDir.AbsolutePath;
 string mediaDirPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalMediaDirs()?.First()?.AbsolutePath;
        
 string filePath = Path.Combine(mediaDirPath, "example.txt");

 File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello, Media!");

 filePath = Path.Combine(obbDirPath, "example.txt");

 File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello, Obb!");


that didnt work for me. writing in Downloads folder is ok and did it without android native code, with MAUI, but my target is Phone/Android/data//files ....

and you expect that file should be visible through file manager?

yes. like games got cache files stored in that location and Im able to check these binaries and so on...

@red_panda check my updated answer, I dont see files of any other apps in Phone/Android/data .... that's simply because we cant see them. But we can see in media and obb files
